# Aggregating by multiple variables including time

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, xts

I'm new to programming in R (and for that matter, programming at all...) and I'm trying to do some data analysis for a project for my class. I have some data that looks like this:

| Id | Time | Heartrate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1341231 | 2016-04-12 07:23:30 | 95 |
| 1341231 | 2016-04-12 07:23:40 | 101 |
| 1341231 | 2016-04-12 07:23:50 | 92 |
| 1341231 | 2016-04-12 07:24:00 | 87 |
| 2342383 | 2016-04-12 07:23:30 | 60 |

This is data from wearable fitness trackers, in 5 or 10 second intervals. It's a fairly large dataset, with more than 2 million entries. What I would like to do is: for each Id (aka each user), summarize the seconds data by hour, returning the average heart rate for each hour. So I’d like output that looks something like this:

| Id | Time | Heartrate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1341231 | 2016-04-12 07:00 | 95 |
| 1341231 | 2016-04-12 08:00 | 82 |
| 1341231 | 2016-04-12 09:00 | 80 |
| 1341231 | 2016-04-12 10:00 | 100 |
| 2342383 | 2016-04-12 07:00 | 65 |

The dates were originally strings, so I parsed them with `lubridate.` But after that, things started to go awry.

So, I turn to my best technique: copy-pasting half-understood code.

First, I tried
`test_df <- aggregate(Heartrate ~ format(as.POSIXct(sechr$Time), "%m-%d-%y %H"), data=sechr, mean)`

but that was no good. As I quickly realized, that dropped the Id out completely, summarizing my data in a more or less useless way.

So, next I tried various formulations of `aggregate`, which doesn't seem to take another argument for another variable, and then experimented with `summarize` and `group_by`, such as below:

`testdf3 <- sechr %>% group_by(c(Time ~ format(as.POSIXct(sechr$Time))), "%m-%d-%y %H", Id) %>% summarise(avg_hr=sum(Heartrate))`

Needless to say, basically guessing didn't work at all. I produced a lot of errors and several goofy, useless dataframes.

Basically, what I need is a way to say "for each distinct Id, give me the mean of each hour." I think using `xts` is the way to go? Maybe? but I'm puzzled about how to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: use `aggregate(Heartrate~Id+h, transform(sechr, h = format(Tme, "%F %H")), mean)`

Comment: Check the class of column `Time` and if it already is of class `"POSIXct"`, try `aggregate(Heartrate ~ Id + format(Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H"), data = sechr, mean)`.

Comment: Or add `Id` to the RHS of your first attempt.

Comment: Thank you both for your commentary! I couldn't quite get aggregate to these ways, but it may well be user error. The groupby + summarise answer from below works well for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren’t *too* far off with your `group_by() %>% summarize()` attempt; I cleaned it up a bit, and specified timezone in `format()` using `lubridate::tz()`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sechr %>% 
  group_by(Id, Time = format(Time, "%m-%d-%y %H", tz = tz(Time))) %>%
  summarise(avg_hr = mean(Heartrate)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
       Id Time        avg_hr
    <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1 1341231 04-12-16 07   93.8
2 2342383 04-12-16 07   60
```

An alternative to `format()`, if you’d like to keep `Time` as a datetime object, would be to round down to the hour using `lubridate::floor_date()`.

```
sechr %>% 
  group_by(Id, Time = floor_date(Time, "hour")) %>%
  summarise(avg_hr = mean(Heartrate)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
       Id Time                avg_hr
    <dbl> <dttm>               <dbl>
1 1341231 2016-04-12 07:00:00   93.8
2 2342383 2016-04-12 07:00:00   60
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm glad I wasn't barking up the wrong tree entirely. This a) works, and b) makes sense so that I understand how the group by and summarise functions work together a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

An approach using my package `timeplyr`.
As the name suggests, it is a time extension to dplyr and so works naturally with tidyverse syntax.

```r
# remotes::install_github("NicChr/timeplyr")
library(timeplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
sechr %>%
  mutate(Time = ymd_hms(Time)) %>%
  group_by(Id) %>%
  time_summarise(avg_hr = mean(Heartrate), 
                 time = Time, by = "hour")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   Id [2]
#>        Id Time                avg_hr
#>     <int> <dttm>               <dbl>
#> 1 1341231 2016-04-12 07:23:30   93.8
#> 2 2342383 2016-04-12 07:23:30   60
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

`time_summarise()` is more flexible as you can aggregate by any time unit.

```r
sechr2 <- sechr %>%
  mutate(Time = ymd_hms(Time)) %>%
  group_by(Id)
sechr2 %>%
  time_summarise(avg_hr = mean(Heartrate), 
                 time = Time, by = "30 seconds")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   Id [2]
#>        Id Time                avg_hr
#>     <int> <dttm>               <dbl>
#> 1 1341231 2016-04-12 07:23:30     96
#> 2 1341231 2016-04-12 07:24:00     87
#> 3 2342383 2016-04-12 07:23:30     60
sechr2 %>%
  time_summarise(avg_hr = mean(Heartrate), 
                 time = Time, by = "minute")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   Id [2]
#>        Id Time                avg_hr
#>     <int> <dttm>               <dbl>
#> 1 1341231 2016-04-12 07:23:30   93.8
#> 2 2342383 2016-04-12 07:23:30   60
sechr2 %>%
  time_summarise(avg_hr = mean(Heartrate), 
                 time = Time, by = "30 minutes")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#> # Groups:   Id [2]
#>        Id Time                avg_hr
#>     <int> <dttm>               <dbl>
#> 1 1341231 2016-04-12 07:23:30   93.8
#> 2 2342383 2016-04-12 07:23:30   60
```

You can also complete missing gaps in time if for some reason you didn't have data for certain intervals.

```r
sechr2 %>%
  time_complete(time = Time, to = min(Time) + years(1))
#> Assuming a time granularity of 10 seconds
#> # A tibble: 6,307,202 x 3
#> # Groups:   Id [2]
#>         Id Time                Heartrate
#>  *   <int> <dttm>                  <int>
#>  1 1341231 2016-04-12 07:23:30        95
#>  2 1341231 2016-04-12 07:23:40       101
#>  3 1341231 2016-04-12 07:23:50        92
#>  4 1341231 2016-04-12 07:24:00        87
#>  5 1341231 2016-04-12 07:24:10        NA
#>  6 1341231 2016-04-12 07:24:20        NA
#>  7 1341231 2016-04-12 07:24:30        NA
#>  8 1341231 2016-04-12 07:24:40        NA
#>  9 1341231 2016-04-12 07:24:50        NA
#> 10 1341231 2016-04-12 07:25:00        NA
#> # ... with 6,307,192 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather makeshift solution using `{data.table}`.

I have replicated the first few rows to test it out.

```
sechr <- data.table(Id = c("1341231", "1341231", "1341231", "1341231", "2342383"),
                    Time = c("2016-04-12 07:23:30", "2016-04-12 07:23:40",
                             "2016-04-12 07:23:50", "2016-04-12 07:24:00",
                             "2016-04-12 07:23:30"),
                    Heartrate = c(95, 101, 92, 87, 60))
```

Here I determine the hour by referring to the number right before the first occurrence of colon (and the date, of course).

```
sechr[, TimeH := gsub(":.*", ":00:00", Time)]
sechr_ByIDHour <- sechr[, .(Heartrate = mean(Heartrate)), .(Id, TimeH)]
```